# Is a for loop the equivalent to a method?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to understand closures but every single example I have seen and read all contain the same examples of functions inside functions, but all of the closure problems I face contain functions inside  loops.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log(i));
}
```

Take the above code as an example, `setTimeout` is an API method inside the browser and `i` is not being passed through.

```
function sayHello(name) {
  var text = 'Hello ' + name;
  var say = function() { console.log(text); }
  say();
}
sayHello('Joe');
```

The above frequently [used closure example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work]) is not the same because I have called `setTimeOut` inside a `for loop`. `setTimeout` is **not** defined/created inside the function/loop, I am only calling it. It could therefore be defined somewhere else, **outside** of the function, which goes against closures entirely. What am I missing here o.O

Secondly, I have a `for loop`, not a function above another function. Is the variable declaration above the equivalent?

Comment: The closure in the first example is `() => ...`. Where `setTimeout` is defined doesn't matter. No, a loop is not equivalent to a method.

Comment: The loop and the function example is the same, in the loop the relevant part is not the `setTimeout` but the `() => console.log(i)`. So with both `function() { console.log(text); }` and `() => console.log(i)` you defined a function that creates a closure over a variable (`i` or `text`)

Comment: A closure is any function that references variables defined in the outer scope. So the anonymous function you're passing to `setTimeout` is a closure because it uses `i`, and `say` is a closure because it uses `text`.

Comment: The closure is always the inner function. What it closes over depends on the scope it is in, and changing that is the solution to your problem. A `for (var …) {` does not create its own scope, a `for (let …) {` and a `function(…) {` do create scopes.